# Where are the .db files saved?

Tags: sqlite, qt

I want to use SQLite databases with Qt. I don't have much experience with SQLite and I've encountered this problem.
According to a tutorial, the following command creates a .db file: 
`>sqlite3 test.db`
My question is where does this file get stored on the system because I need to link it with my Qt application.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets created in the folder you invoked the command.

Answer (score 0):

Using python, the following code creates example databases in the current directory:

```
    import sqlite3
    import random

    N = 1000

    def build(name):

        connection = sqlite3.connect(name + ".db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE Data (question1 INTEGER, question2 Real)""")
        for i in range(N):
            vals = (random.choice((0,1,2,3)), round(random.gauss(0,1),2))
            cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Data VALUES (?,?)""",vals)
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
    for name in ["name1","name2","name3"]:
        build(name)
```